# refresh an included page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page index.php
Inside of it is a friendlist that updates the db with a button click without refreshing the page. Now I want that only the friendlist refreshs so its updated

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
            include ("friendlist.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

friendlist.php:

```
<script>
function adduser() {

    var data=$("#adduserform").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addfriend.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data)
           {
               //refresh myFriendlist or requser so its updated
           }
                });
}


</script>

<div id="myFriendlist" class="friendlist-content">
    <?php if(!empty($request)) { ?>
    <div id="req">
    <h2 id="reqh">Anfragen</h2>
    <?php foreach($request as $row) {
    $row['userAname'] = (strlen($row['userAname']) > 5) ? substr($row['userAname'], 0, 5) . '...' : $row['userAname'];
    ?>
    <div id="requser">
        <a class="reqimg" style="padding:0px;" href="user.php?id=<?php echo ($row['id']);?>">
            <img  class="reqpb" src="./users/<?php echo ($row['userAid']); ?>/pb.jpg" alt="Bild nicht gefunden" onerror="this.src='./img/no_pb.png';"></img>
        </a>
        <a class="reqnm" style="padding:0px;" href="user.php?id=<?php echo ($row['userAid']);?>"><?php echo $row['userAname']; ?></a>

        <a href="javascript:adduser();" id="accept" title="Aktzeptieren"><img id="aimg" src="./img/accepticon.png"></a>
        <form id="adduserform" name="adduserform">
                <input type="hidden" id="reqid" name="reqid" value="<?php echo $row['userAid'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="reqnm" name="reqnm" value="<?php echo $row['userAname'];?>" />
        </form>

        <a href="javascript:rejectuser();" id="dntacpt" title="Ablehnen"><img id="aimg" src="./img/dntaccepticon.png"></a>

    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh an external file using ajax. For example, if you had a div with the id "friendslist" you could refresh its contents this way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "friendlist.php"
}).done(function(response) {
  $( '#friendslist' ).html( response );
});
```

The documentation for ajax is on the jQuery site here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make "addfriend.php" to return the new complete list of users, so that would be:

`<?php foreach($request as $row) {
    $row['userAname'] = (strlen($row['userAname']) > 5) ? substr($row['userAname'], 0, 5) . '...' : $row['userAname'];
?>`

you could use that response, which you will receive when you do the AJAX call, to refresh the friendlist, using the jquery HTML function (http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this code but not tested

first update your index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="friendlist">
<?php
        include ("friendlist.php");
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then update your addfriend.php as like

```
<?php 

 // your code here 

// then include your frindlist.php content
include 'yourpath/frindlist.php'
?>
```

then update your javascript code like this

```
function adduser() {
var data=$("#adduserform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addfriend.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data)
       {
           $('#friendlist').html(data);
       }
      });
     }
```